# Angular Unit Testing - Mock async calls of injected services with TestBed

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test, angular-test

I need to write unit tests for the following `DataService` ,

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
   constructor(private config: ConfigService, private http: HttpClient) {

   }

   .....

   someMethod(){
        let apiUrl = this.config.get('api').url;   // LINE 1
   }
}
```

The `ConfigService` is injected to `DataService` that has a `load` function which gets the configuration from a json file. This `load` function will be invoked when the app is initialized.

```
export function configServiceFactory(config: ConfigService) {
    return () => config.load();
}

...

providers: [
        ConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: configServiceFactory,
            deps: [ConfigService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
```

Here's a part of `data-service.spect.ts` file,

```
...

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [DataService, ConfigService]
    });

    mock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(DataService);
  });

....
```

so when i run the test, in `LINE 1` i get that the `this.config.get('api')` is undefined. I can understand that it is because the `ConfigService` did not load the data from JSON. So now how i can i make the injected services also make the async calls during unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing unit tests, you would want to mock every dependency you have. You already do this for `HttpClient` by importing `HttpClientTestingModule` so you need to do the same for `ConfigService`.

There are two ways to do so.

**1- Fake Service (Stub)**

```
export class ConfigServiceStub {
    get(input: string) {
        // return static value instead of calling an API
    }
}

...

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        providers: [DataService, 
                   {provide: ConfigService, useClass: ConfigServiceStub}
        ]
    });

    mock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(DataService);
});
```

With this way, your `DataService` won't call the real `ConfigService`, but instead it'll call the `get` method of `ConfigServiceStub`. When using `Stub`s, you don't need to worry about other dependencies `ConfigService` has. You just implement the methods that you want to override.

**2-Spies**

You can create spies on the method that you don't want to invoke.

```
it('run some test', inject([DataService], (service: DataService) => {
    spyOn(service.config, 'get').and.returnValue('someString');

    // run your tests here
});
```

Even though, `ConfigService.get` method won't get called in the example above, Angular still needs to create an instance of `ConfigService` which may be hard to do so in some examples or may result in creating too many other services for simple test.

I'd go with option 1

For more information on spies, check [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)

Comment: In the option 1, then i have to use Spy, Stub & Mock together. Is that the standard way of doing it?

Comment: @DRB In the first option, you don't need to spy it (you can though). Also, it's not the "standart" way. It's just a way as I shown you two of them. Use whatever fits your needs.